# data missing fill NAN with addition of 10

Tags: python, missing-data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'From_To': ['LoNDon_paris', 'MAdrid_miLAN', 'londON_StockhOlm','Budapest_PaRis', 'Brussels_londOn'],
'FlightNumber': [10045, np.nan, 10065, np.nan, 10085],
'RecentDelays':  [[23, 47], [], [24, 43, 87], [13], [67, 32]], 
'Airline': ['KLM(!)', '<Air France> (12)', '(British Airways. )', '12. Air France', '"Swiss Air"']})

df

               Airline  FlightNumber           From_To  RecentDelays
0               KLM(!)       10045.0      LoNDon_paris      [23, 47]
1    <Air France> (12)           NaN      MAdrid_miLAN            []
2  (British Airways. )       10065.0  londON_StockhOlm  [24, 43, 87]
3       12. Air France           NaN    Budapest_PaRis          [13]
4          "Swiss Air"       10085.0   Brussels_londOn      [67, 32]
```

Some values in the the FlightNumber column are missing. These numbers are meant to increase by 10 with each row so 10055 and 10075 need to be put in place. Fill in these missing numbers and make the column an integer column (instead of a float column).

Comment: Is the `FlightNumber` missing from every second row or what's the problem here?

Comment: I downvoted, because homework with no attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this would work.

```
for i in range(1, df['FlightNumber'].count() + 1):
      if pd.isnull(df.loc[i,'FlightNumber']):
          df.loc[i, 'FlightNumber'] = df.loc[i-1, 'FlightNumber'] + 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

`df['FlightNumber'] = df['FlightNumber'].interpolate().astype(int)`